# Seaborn - disable xtick interpolation

Tags: pandas, seaborn

I'm plotting a dataframe in seaborn with 2 (datetime) points separated by a week. What I want is 2 points on the x axis but seaborn is giving 7 which is messy and confusing.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Branch': {0: 'Branch 1', 1: 'Branch 1'}, 'Value £': {0: 24.0, 1: 7.5},
 'W/c': {0: datetime.date(2019, 5, 27), 1: datetime.date(2019, 6, 3)}})

    df
   Branch         W/c  Value £
0  Branch 1  2019-05-27     24.0
1  Branch 1  2019-06-03      7.5



    sns.set()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters(explicit=True)
    ax = sns.lineplot(data = df,  x='W/c', y='Value £', hue='Branch')
    fig.savefig('plot.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Expected result: 2 points on the x axis

Actual result: 7 points on x axis (each day between and including the dates in the df).

How do I get just 2 values on the x axis?

Thanks

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a `pointplot` instead?

Comment: Point plot does the trick - many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all but the first and the last tick labels using the following. Here `range(1, len(xtcks)-1)` will loop from 2nd tick up to the second last tick and make their labels hide

---

---

**Complete answer**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Branch': {0: 'Branch 1', 1: 'Branch 1'}, 'Value £': {0: 24.0, 1: 7.5},
                             'W/c': {0: datetime.date(2019, 5, 27), 1: datetime.date(2019, 6, 3)}})


sns.set()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters(explicit=True)
ax = sns.lineplot(data = df,  x='W/c', y='Value £', hue='Branch')
fig.canvas.draw()

xticks = ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()
for i in range(1, len(xticks)-1):
    xticks[i].label1.set_visible(False)

fig.savefig('plot.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sheldore. It's so odd that we have to use a workaround for this - I'm not sure how well your solution will scale for >2 points and would rather just have the markers in the original dataframe.

Comment: @user2839288 : Are you having efficiency issues with this approach? How much time does it take for your real data?

Comment: No efficiency issues - it just feels a bit clunky. Thanks anyway.